# windows store Directx app which uses javascript Api's like facebook's graph API for data source

Tags: javascript, facebook, windows-8, directx

I want to make a windows store 3D app using directx but my most of data will comes from facebook's Graph API and twitter's REST API .which are available in javascript ..what are options for me to make this app? can i do this in a single app?

Comment: Facebook API and Twitter API are available in several languages... for example in C#, Java, Javascript etc. Any reason you want to use javascript in your application ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use both the Facebook and Twitter API from within C++.  See [Casablanca Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/casablanca.aspx) for example.  This way you will not have to pay the performance penalty of calling C++ from Javascript or vice versa.  I am assuming you are writing the app in DirectX and C++ because of good performance and better graphics to begin with.